# Adding limit parameters to bar charts in Pentaho Report Designer

Tags: mdx, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I am using Pentaho Report Designer to generate reports from my olap cube using mdx. I want to generate bar chart reports from Pentaho Report Designer. I have 50000 records and writing a MDX query to display keywords along with their count. Problem is bar chart that is created is of 50000 records, but I want to pass two parameters that act as start and end value to display  i.e user is prompted to enter starting and ending parameters (suppose he enters 1 and 10) so 10 records should be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know the specifics of Pentaho MDX, but in general, I would use the following approach, assuming the 50000 records are in hierarchy `[DimA].[Record]`:

```
WITH SET [Selected Records] AS
     SubSet([DimA].[Record].[Record].Members,
            ParamRef('start') - 1, 
            ParamRef('end') - ParamRef('start') + 1
           )
SELECT { [Measures].[Count] }
       ON COLUMNS,
       [Selected Records]
       ON ROWS
FROM [MyCube]
```

I am a bit guessing about the use of `ParamRef` in Mondrian MDX here. The `SubSet` function is described for Analysis Services here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144767.aspx

Comment: ..thank you for your answer it almost worked but with subsets i am not able to use filters . Any pointers on using filters with subset would be really helpful

Comment: Could you show an example of how you are using the Filter currently?

Comment: Query is SELECT Subset
   (order([Keyword].[Keyword].Members,[Measures].[Keyword count],desc
      )
   ,0
   ,10
   ) ON 1,
NON EMPTY {Hierarchize({[Measures].[Keyword count]})} ON 0
FROM [BasicSearch]
where [Timestamp].[2012] . this timestamp filter is not working with subset

Comment: You could copy the filter to the value tuple of the `order` as well, using `order([Keyword].[Keyword].Members, ([Measures].[Keyword count], [Timestamp].[2012]), desc )`.